# Chain in a CL with Multiple Keys using OVRDBF

Tags: ibm-midrange

Is there a way to do a operation like Chain in CL with multiple keys? Below would work for a single Key:
For example if I have a file `EMPMST`, with Key as `EMPNO`, and I if I have to chain with Employee as 101 then I can use below:

```
OVRDBF     FILE(EMPMST) POSITION(*KEY 1 EMPMSTr 101)
RCVF
```

If I have multiple keys in the `Empmst`(`EMPNO`(101) and `EMPNAME`(JIM)) , then how would I use this command? I know that second parameter would be a 2. But what would be the fourth parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/ovrdbf.htm#OVRDBF.POSITION)

Note that `EMPNO` is passed as a quoted string if a positive zoned decimal value.

```
OVRDBF     FILE(EMPMST) POSITION(*KEY 2 EMPMSTr '101JIM')
```

Note that if `EMPNO` is a packed field, you'd need to use a hexadecimal literal.

```
OVRDBF     FILE(EMPMST) POSITION(*KEY 2 EMPMSTr x'101FD1C9D4')
```

You also need to use hexadecimal literals for negative zoned decimals.

Comment: Ohok. .Thanks Charles. So I understand that we just add the additional Keys as next parameters.

Comment: Hi Charles.. Actually that did not work. But I figured out how it would work. So if both are Strings, it would be  OVRDBF     FILE(EMPMST) POSITION(*KEY 2 EMPMSTr '101JIM'). Now if First Key length is 3 and second Key Length is 3, then it will understand that first key is 101 and second Key is JIM. Kind of like a DS.

Comment: And also I noticed that the Keys had to be hardcoded. When I am putting it in a Variable, it is not working

Comment: @AS400User I've corrected the answer...a character variable should work...as long as it's char(6)....